# Getting the Contents of a Gridview in Row Command

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is the code in UI

```
<asp:TemplateField>
     <ItemTemplate>  
          <asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" Text="AFE" />
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
--</Columns>
```

I Want to Get the Details of All Fields in Text boxes in Same page when ever I click on the Button Edit. I Tried using :

```
  protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
     {
    if (e.CommandName == "Edit")
    { 

    GridViewRow Row = (GridViewRow)(((Button)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);

    string text = Row.Cells[2].Text;

    }
```

But I am getting "" in string text..

This is screenshot of my grid view
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You can use the row index stored in `command argument` to find a row where `Edit` button is clicked.
2. Now you can find the `TextBox` in that row where cell index location is 2.
3. Then get the `Text` of your `TextBox`.

   ```
   protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
   {
       if(e.CommandName == "Edit")
       {
           int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
           GridViewRow clickedRow = CustomersGridView.Rows[index];

           TextBox myTextBox = (TextBox)clickedRow.Cells[2].FindControl("TextBoxName");
           string text = myTextBox.Text;
       }
   }
   ```

In ASPX page, you need to handle row command event like this:

```
    <asp:gridview id="GridView1" 
        datasourceid="DataSource" 
        autogeneratecolumns="false"
        onrowcommand="GridView1_RowCommand"
        runat="server">
    </asp:gridview>
```

Comment: Thanx !! Dat Worked!!!!! One more thing regarding same ,,what are the "Command Arguments" and "DataItemIndex",,how can i use them effectively...any links or info welcome!!!!

Comment: Glad that it worked for you. You might refer to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.commandargument(v=vs.110).aspx) if you want to know more about `Command Arguments`.

Answer (score 1):

You can access to `GridViewRow` using following code (*note: the `Button` must be the control that has `CommandName/CommandArgument`*):

```
var row = (GridViewRow)(((Button)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);
```

Then simply use `FindControl` method on `found row` to find your target control, *for ex.*:

```
var txtSomething = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtSomething");
```

Also you can access to `RowIndex` using `row.RowIndex`.

*I recommended avoid using `row.Cells[INDEX].FindControl()`, just `row.FindControl` works just fine, targeting specific `cell` isn't good, if you change the markup and add/remove some columns, (maybe) you need to update the `INDEX` too, so don't do that* :)

Answer (score -1):

You need to find the TextBox control in the cell and get the value from it.

```
string text = (TextBox)Row.FindControl["MyTextBoxId"].Text;
```