# How to get the cell index of textbox in my gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, textbox

How to get the cell index of textbox in my gridview ?

My code :

```
protected void txt_1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     int progSer = int.Parse(Session["prog"].ToString());
     RadNumericTextBox txt = (RadNumericTextBox)sender;

     GridViewRow r = (GridViewRow)txt.NamingContainer;
     //now i want to get the cell index of my fired textbox ,say this text box is in the second column so i want to get index 2
}
```

Comment: Why don't you know it? Do you use the same handler for every textbox? Also, index starts always with 0.

Comment: @TimSchmelter yes one handler for the all cuz i have many text boxes ,i differentiate between them by the sender

Comment: @just_name please take look at this link maybe helps you somehow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26861489/call-function-behind-the-image-button-in-gridview/26861845#26861845

Comment: Refer to this thread:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22394919/getting-the-contents-of-a-gridview-in-row-command

it's has a good Answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`TableCellCollection.GetCellIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.tablecellcollection.getcellindex(v=vs.110).aspx) and a loop to find the cell of the `TextBox`:

```
TableCell cell = null;
Control parent = txt;
while ((parent = parent.Parent) != null && cell == null)
    cell = parent as TableCell;
int indexOfTextBoxCell = -1;
if (cell != null)
    indexOfTextBoxCell = r.Cells.GetCellIndex(cell);
```